# how to insert a time in oracle 10g database

Tags: oracle10g

I want to insert date and time in oracle database, I have created the table with columns

```
create table myadmin 
(  employe_id number(5), 
  supervisor Varchar2(20),
  department Varchar2(20),
  action Varchar2(20),
  sdate date, 
  stime date) 
While inserting the values below it gives an error. Please tell me how to insert the time ?

insert into myadmin 
(  employe_id,supervisor,department,action,sdate,stime) values 
(83,'gaurav','helpdesk','pick','23-jan-2013','09:43:00');
```

Comment: Why do you want the date and time as separate columns? You can't really insert just a time anyway - it would have to be a time on a nominal date, or an interval, or a string. None of which seem useful if they're related to an actual date anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use keyword to_date for date insert in oracle like this.

```
to_date('23-01-2013','dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Basically you have to use keyword to_date('your date','your date format').

You can also add date and time together if you want and it would be something like this

```
 to_date('23-01-2013 09:43:00','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Answer (score 1):

A date in Oracle always has a date part and a time part. Having date and time in two separate columns only makes sense, if it can occur that date is null and time is not. (And still, you could set date to an improbable value like 1.1.0001 then.)

However, if you want to stick to those two separate fields, then make your string a datetime with the to_date function specifying the format used:

```
insert into myadmin 
(  employe_id,supervisor,department,action,sdate,stime) values 
(83,'gaurav','helpdesk','pick',to_date('23-01-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('09:43:00', 'hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Comment: `stime` will still have a date part as you said; it will default to the first day of the current month, so if run today you'd get an `stime` of `2013-09-01 09:43:00`.

Comment: One note: If you want to convert strings with month names or abbreviations (like jan, feb, etc.) then state the language used, for oct is valid in English but not in German for instance. to_date('23-oct-2013', 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')

Comment: @Alex Poole: Good comment. When working with that column, one must always make sure not to use the date part.